# extract all hyperlinks ( from external website ) using node.js and request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

Right now our app writes the source code of nodejs.org to the console.
We'd like it to write all hyperlinks of nodejs.org instead.
Maybe we need just one line of code to get the links from `body`.

app.js:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');

var request = require("request");



request("http://nodejs.org/", function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error)
        console.log(body);
    else
        console.log(error);
});
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You are probably looking for either [jsdom](https://npmjs.org/package/jsdom) , [jquery](https://npmjs.org/package/jquery) or [cheerio](https://npmjs.org/package/cheerio). What you are doing is called screen scraping, extracting data from a site. jsdom/jquery offer complete set of tools but cheerio is much faster.

Here is a cheerio example :

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var searchTerm = 'screen+scraping';
var url = 'http://www.bing.com/search?q=' + searchTerm;
request(url, function(err, resp, body){
  $ = cheerio.load(body);
  links = $('a'); //jquery get all hyperlinks
  $(links).each(function(i, link){
    console.log($(link).text() + ':\n  ' + $(link).attr('href'));
  });
});
```

You choose whatever is best for you.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the document.links results by using cheerio?

Comment: Can't u directly call `links.each` and inside the function use `$(this).text()` and `$(this).attr('href')`? At least in `cheerio` this works.

Comment: If you want to get absolute url, use `url.resolve(crawl_url, $(link).attr('href'))`

Comment: For `requests` library, I get deprecation warning when installing it. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

package.json

```
    {
      "name": "url_extractor",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "tool to extract all urls from website",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "author": "sandip shelke",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.24.0",
        "cheerio": "^1.0.0-rc.10"
      }
    }
```

Index.js

```
        const axios = require('axios');
        var cheerio = require('cheerio');

        var baseUrl = 'target website base url';

        (async () => {
            
            try 
            {
                let homePageLinks = await getLinksFromURL(baseUrl)
                console.log(homePageLinks);
            } catch (e) { console.log(e); }

        })();



        async function getLinksFromURL(url) {

            try {
                let links = [];
                let httpResponse = await axios.get(url);

                let $ = cheerio.load(httpResponse.data);
                let linkObjects = $('a'); // get all hyperlinks

                linkObjects.each((index, element) => {
                    links.push({
                        text: $(element).text(), // get the text
                        href: $(element).attr('href'), // get the href attribute
                    });
                });

                return links;
            } catch (e) { console.log(e) }

        }
```

This code will fetch links from home page only, Run it recursively to load all links from webpage.

Run npm install & then npm start to run above code considering you have node installed.